# Improving methods in Java

Tags: java

I have recently started a course where the main language we are learning at the moment is Java.

I have been tasked with creating a program that allows people to vote on two candidates - the program then counts the votes, and depending on how man votes have been made depends on what is displayed.

Here is the part I am concerned with at the moment:

```
public String printResults(){
       if(candidate1Votes == 0 && candidate2Votes == 0)
  {
      System.out.println ("No votes cast, results cannot be displayed.");
      return "No votes cast, results cannot be displayed.";
  }
  else if(this.completed == false)
  {
      System.out.println ("Voting has not finished");
      return "Voting has not finished";
  }

  else if(this.completed == true)
  {
      System.out.println ("Voting has finished, no more votes will be allowed.");
      return "Voting has finished, no more votes will be allowed";
  }
  {
      double totalVotes =  this.candidate1Votes + this.candidate2Votes;
      double cand1Share = (double) this.candidate1Votes/totalVotes*100;
      double cand2Share = (double) this.candidate2Votes/totalVotes*100;

      System.out.format(candidate1 + " received %3.1f percent of the votes\n", cand1Share);
      System.out.format(candidate2 + " received %3.1f percent of the votes\n", cand2Share);
      return "v";
  }
```

}

Originally I used void in this method, but part of our task was to then change it to a string value.  This is where I am struggling - once I set completed to true, it is still allowing me to cast votes.  I know that this code is incomplete but I can't finish it as I am unsure what to do!  These were the next parts to the questions.

1. Modify your printResults method so that it applies the first two rules. Note that the value of the completed field indicates whether or not voting is complete. The method should be modified to return a String which indicates whether printing has been successful.
2. Modify your vote method to apply the third rule. 
   Test your methods by creating an instance and doing the following – before
   doing each test note the result you expect to get, and compare this with what you actually get:
   • Try to print results immediately
   • Cast votes for both candidates and try to print results
   • Set the completed field to true by calling setCompleted
   • Try to cast a vote for a candidate
   • Print the results

I am new to this (this is my first year) and have managed to do okay in my books to get this far, however any help on this next issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: doing **if(this.completed)** instead of **if(this.completed == true)** will be an improvement for many many people

Comment: Put down a first answer to get you going; maybe you want to further comment/update your question ... if my answer helps you to *clarify* your question. As I am not really sure where you are stuck right now!

Comment: best regards to your teacher, but she should stop teaching the use of _return values_ for error handling (in Java). It has better concepts.

Answer (score 0):

First of your code is unnecessary complicated, which makes it hard to read/enhance. It can *easily* simplified, like

```
public String printResults(){

  if(candidate1Votes == 0 && candidate2Votes == 0) {
    System.out.println ("No votes cast, results cannot be displayed.");
    return "No votes cast, results cannot be displayed.";
  } // you returned ... NO need for ELSE!

  if(this.completed == false) { 
    System.out.println ("Voting has not finished");
    return "Voting has not finished";
  }

  // it is very clear here that completed must be true!
  double totalVotes =  this.candidate1Votes + this.candidate2Votes;
  double cand1Share = (double) this.candidate1Votes/totalVotes*100;
  double cand2Share = (double) this.candidate2Votes/totalVotes*100;

  System.out.format(candidate1 + " received %3.1f percent of the votes\n", cand1Share);
  System.out.format(candidate2 + " received %3.1f percent of the votes\n", cand2Share);
  return "v";
}
```

Probably that easier-to-read code is all that you need to get you going!

Comment: `this.completed == false` better be like `!completed`

Comment: @RomanSamoylenko In the end, this is a *style* question. I kept his style here, in order to **not** have him overlook that ! not there.

Comment: @JimHawkins Actually, I am only using multiple returns in short methods. Because only in short methods it is easy to grasp that you have multiple exit points. Like in this case: three pretty similar cases, easy to read and get. Those short "straight" paths are *easier* to digest than any if-else-if-else chains.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code the last block will never be reached because either you have no votes or you have votes and in that case completed will be either true or false and will thus reach always one of the `else if`s and they all return a string. So I wonder why how you can cast any votes at all.

You could also post the code where you call printResults and setCompleted to see where the problem lies.

Some more hints for improving your code:

- Sometimes you have the opening bracket on the same line and sometimes on the next. You should probably choose one style
- It is not necessary to surround the last code block with brackets
- `if (this.completed == true)` and `else if (this.completed == false)` is a bit redundant and can be written like: `if (this.completed)` and `if (!this.completed)`. Also you can write

  ```
  if (this.completed) {
      ...
  } else {
      ....
  }
  ```

  because if completed is not true it can only be false.
- Instead of writing every String two times and having to edit it two times in case you want to change something you could also do the following:

  ```
  String msg = "Voting has not finished"
  System.out.println(msg);
  return msg;
  ```